# C# app - How to move all resources out of the main assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, localization

For my C# apps I need to have default/neutral resources placed in a sattelight assembly, such that the output of a build looks like:
MyApp.exe
-AND-
MyApp.resources.dll <- containing default/neutral resources
How can I accomplish this using VS2008 and .NET runtime 2.0 or greater?
Secondary question:
How to keep the resources in the exe, and ALSO create a sattelite assembly dll for en (a complete one, not an empty one that falls back on looking in the main assembly exe).

Comment: What do you want to achieve by moving them out of your main program?

Comment: I can then import the dll into an app called Catalyst by Alchemy Software.  This is one of my dev group's i18n tools.  Once the dll is imported I then 'play' with it in Catalyst (by changing strings and UI control positioning), and eventually I get an output dll that represents the proper resources for a given culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate project called MyApp.Resources that only contains your resources. Have your main project depend on/refer to that project.

Comment: While this could be done, I'm looking for a way to do it without creating a separate project.

Comment: You could create a build task which compiles the resources into a separate assembly, or which copies them to the other project. That way you don't have to manually update two places.

Comment: Would this create an EXE without any embedded resources?
I want an EXE without any embedded resources and a DLL with the default resources.

Comment: Well, no one else has added any comment in some time, so, while I didn't exactly get the answer I was seeking, I'm going to accept what has been offered to this point as an acceptable solution.